# Flutter api showing 'Required parameter missing or invalid'

Tags: flutter, api, rest

Flutter rest API showing 'Required parameter missing or invalid'

```
main() async {      
  final data = {
    'customer': {
      'first_name': 'Karla',
      'last_name': 'Mullins',
      'email': 'KarlaMullins@mailinator.com',
      'phone': '+15142546011',
      'verified_email': true,
      'addresses': [
        {
          'address1': '123 Oak St1',
          'city': 'Ottawa1',
          'province': 'ON',
          'phone': '555-1212',
          'zip': '123 ABC',
          'last_name': 'Mullins',
          'first_name': 'Karla',
          'country': 'CA',
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  var json = jsonEncode(data);
  String username = 'u';
  String password = 'p';
  String basicAuth =
      'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));

  var response = await http.post(url',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': basicAuth,
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    body: json,
  );

  print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

calling rest api with basic authorisation from flutter dart showing Response status: 400
and Response body: {"errors":{"customer":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}.

Comment: Check with the backend dev or api documentation and verify whether you are passing all the expected parameters to your backend or not

Comment: i have checked with postman with same data format.

Comment: Unable to help you, since we don't have access to the API or don't know the implementation logic of that API. If it's working in postman, just cross-check the request in both cases. Check the authentication header in both case. Also in your code there is a `'` near `url` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Change `Accept` into `"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Or application/json, depending on your api.